# Get Tumblr blog's tags without OAuth

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth, tumblr

I am trying to get a list of all posts with tag `gallery-worthy` in my tumblr blog. I was digging into source code of the free theme [CLUB MONACO](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/37252). They had a slideshow js which loads all the posts with tag `featured` and extracts all the pictures.

http://static.tumblr.com/i21wc39/hL6mn3w8d/application.js

Although I couldn't see the unobfuscated source code, I could tell they didn't have an api_key or oauth to access tagged posts. It seems to be making a call to `/tagged/featured`

How did they do that? what url are they calling?

Comment: If by obfuscated, you mean minified, http://jsbeautifier.org is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It's a relative URL - for `sitename.com` or `sitename.tumblr.com`, `/tagged/featured` will append to the main URL. It looks like there's some check that the relative URL is `/` in there but as you say it's hard to tell in such a big script what single letter variables are referencing.

`e.get("/tagged/featured", {} function(t)` is JQuery's way of performing an `XmlHttpRequest` where `function(t)` is the result upon successful completion of the request. You'd have to look into the theme a bit further to find what input t is giving.

Once the HTML is received it's then checked for elements with the `post` class, and subsequently for the `photo` class (a photo post...)

The array `i` receives the image's `data-highres` (full size) URL and `url`, a permalink the post in question and `theme_garden` (set to `true`).

```
var i = [];
            e(t).find(".post").each(function (t, n) {
                5 >= i.length && e(n).hasClass("photo") && i.push({
                    cropped_image: e(n).find("img").attr("data-highres"),
                    url: e(n).attr("data-permalink"),
                    theme_garden: !0
                })
```

and for each of the posts a slide is rendered after which the slideshow is built from the template

```
$template = e.parseHTML(Mustache.render(e("#slideshow_template").html(), {
                slides: i
            })), n.buildCarousel($template)
}, "html")
```

From the looks of things this'll only use page 1 of the `/tagged/...` but to get more you would just add `page/2` for subsequent pages (depending on your settings of posts per page). It looks like this theme is using 5 per page.

Comment: I see.. seems like they are just getting the html response from `/tagged/featured/`. I was under the impression they'd get a JSON response from that REST call

Comment: I may be wrong! I don't use JQuery so perhaps someone else will correct me